# Is there an easy way to append a column to 2-d numpy array in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to know if there is any easy way to append a column to an existing m x n Matrix and convert it to a m x (n+1) Matrix

Comment: I don't get the downvotes. Not every question requires a code example to be clear and well posed.

Comment: @saguthegreat, welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Ya seems pretty brutal out here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> array1 = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
>>> array1
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
>>> add = np.zeros((2,1), dtype=int64)
>>> add
array([[0],
       [0]])
>>> np.append(array1, add, axis=1)
array([[1, 2, 3, 0],
       [4, 5, 6, 0]])


>>> b=np.array([[6],[8]])
>>> np.append(array1,b,axis=1)
array([[1, 2, 3, 6],
       [4, 5, 6, 8]])
```